# How to add thumbnail image to drop down after using jQuery Chosen plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I used jquery chosen plugin to create beautiful dropdown. Dropdown contents are image file names.
 I want to show a small thumbnail of each image file beside of dropdown options.

[image]

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us with some code of what you've done so far, even though I think the question is well formulated.

Comment: There's an extension for Chosen (donnow if versions are coherents) to manage images : http://websemantics.github.io/Image-Select/

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus
Thanks, You solve my issue, please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above extension is not adequate, the image items will be disappear when searching.
Try the following extension:
https://github.com/djgrant/chosen-image
But the config is:

```
$(".my-select").chosenImage({
  disable_search: false
});
```

Answer (score 7):

There's an extension for Chosen  to manage images :

http://websemantics.github.io/Image-Select/